# Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired()

Tags: php, yii

I am having the following form

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'change-password',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'focus'=>array($model,'old-password')
    ));
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'oldPassword'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'oldPassword'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'oldPassword'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');
?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

The above form throws an error as

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in /framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php on line 1414
```

I am new you yii framework so i am unable to guess where the error is. can anyone help

**Edit 1**

```
public static function activeLabelEx($model,$attribute,$htmlOptions=array())
    {
        $realAttribute=$attribute;
        self::resolveName($model,$attribute); // strip off square brackets if any
        $htmlOptions['required']=$model->isAttributeRequired($attribute);
        return self::activeLabel($model,$realAttribute,$htmlOptions);
    }
```

**Edit-2**

If remove `<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'oldPassword'); ?>` am getting error as

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getValidators() on a non-object in CHtml.php on line 2236
```

Comment: You've not supplied the relevant code (where isAttributeRequired is being called). However, (and this might not be a huge surprise if you can read English), the problem is that you're calling this method on an object that hasn't for some reason been initialised, so this is where you need to look.

Comment: check my edit 1 for the line `1414`

Comment: You need to learn how to carry out basic debugging. The problem is that the `$model` object doesn't exist. At the very least you could temporarily add some `print_r` statements to see where the problem is arising. (e.g.: Does it exist inside the activeLabelEx method? Does it exist at the level that calls the activeLabelEx method, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $model variable does not contain a Model object, check if you you pass the correct object in render function.

ex for the create page:

```
/* in the controller class */
public function actionCreate() {
    $model=new YourModel;
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['YourModel']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['YourModel'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
/* in the create.php view */
....
echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model));
....
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller when you render to your view 
check the definition of your model 
 `$model=new Model name;` and check your model has the same attributes (variables)

another error

in the controller when you render to your view 
It is possible that the function takes certain parameters and you have not given it

for example `$id` in the next function

```
public function actionUpdateTeams($id) {

}
```